# Is there any publicly available draft of the American Jobs Plan beyond the fact sheet on whitehouse.gov?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate, legislative-process, specific-legislation

The whitehouse released [this fact sheet](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2021/03/31/fact-sheet-the-american-jobs-plan/) on the American Jobs Plan.  However, there are several ambiguities in the plan so I am trying to find a more detailed draft of the plan.  The House of Reps has [this website](https://docs.house.gov/floor/) to document what bills will be considered for a given time period; however, as of the time I am posting this, the most recent information is from over two weeks ago (March 15, 2021) before the Plan fact sheet was announced.  I also can't seem to find any information from the Senate about any draft of a bill related to the American Jobs Plan.

Can anyone point me to an actual bill draft related to the American Jobs Plan that is currently being considered by some part of congress?

Comment: Probably not, and Congress is not currently considering anything, as it is the Easter break.  Something might get formally drafted and published after the recess ends on 12 April.

Comment: Isn't that undercovered by the infrastructure bill/plan, which is yet to be discussed in congress?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that no bill exactly tracking the President's proposal has been introduced in Congress at this time. Components of his proposed legislation closely track existing legislative bills (e.g. related to Broadband infrastructure), but there is no one bill as I write this that matches it based upon a [Govtrack.us search](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/browse?text=American%20Jobs%20#bill_type%5B%5D=3,2&sort=relevance).

The President, of course, does not have the power to introduce legislation in Congress, so a bill proposed by the President is, formally speaking, no more than a suggestion to his Congressional allies.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like to be a strategy document setting out the vision of the vision of the Biden adminisration - hence the 'ambiguities'. The strategy is Keynesian with large scale expenditure on public infrastructure partly predicated on the changes required to the economy due to climate change. This sounds very much like the much heralded Green New Deal.

I imagine that there are detailed proposals - after all, to draw up such a strategy document requires a great deal of planning and the Green New Deal has been trailed for some time. But obviously nothing yet for public consumption. These will come in due course.